# problems with the mobile version of clicking the href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had enabled  tags and they seems to have some trouble running on the mobile device.

I had the following Jquery code which works well on desktops:

```
$(".tabs-menu a").bind("click touchend",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    var tabid = $(this).attr("id");
    var listItems = $("#tabbling li");
    var lista = $("#tabbling li a");
    listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li).attr('data-mode');
        if(product == tabid) {
            $(li).addClass('current');
        }else {
            $(li).removeClass('current')
        }
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#tabbling").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

But it is not working in the mobile, when i click it it goes to undefined page showing me 404 error, i am not sure what s going wrong here

Comment: `when i click it it goes to undefined page showing me 404 error`->it means problem is not in your jQuery code. Problem is in link `href`

Comment: Would you provide html code also ?

Comment: this site: prolexmedia.ca/home.cfm - the main thing is to check the tabs-menu